# how to display calender particular dates in various color in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image]
display calender particular dates in various color in xamarin forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `XamForms.Controls.Calendar`.

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/

Code Sample on GitHub: https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <controls:Calendar
        x:Name="calendar"
        Padding="10,0,10,0"
        DisabledBorderColor="Black"
        SelectedBorderWidth="4"
        ShowNumberOfWeek="false"
        StartDay="Monday"
        TitleLabelTextColor="Purple"
        TitleLeftArrowTextColor="Blue" />
</StackLayout>
```

Code:

Use `SpecialDates` to display calender particular dates in various color.

```
 calendar.SpecialDates = new List<XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate>
        {
           new XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate(new DateTime(2020, 1, 25)){ BackgroundColor = Color.Green, TextColor = Color.Accent, BorderColor = Color.Lime, BorderWidth=8, Selectable = true },
           new XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate(new DateTime(2020, 1, 26)){BackgroundColor = Color.Green, TextColor = Color.Accent, BorderColor = Color.Lime, BorderWidth = 8, Selectable = true },
           new XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate(new DateTime(2020, 1, 27)){BackgroundColor = Color.Green, TextColor = Color.Accent, BorderColor = Color.Lime, BorderWidth=8, Selectable = true }
        };
```

I use three days for reference.

[image]